# Where to find a list of Bitcoin attorneys?

Tags: legal

Does anyone know where to find a list of attorneys well-versed in Bitcoin?  A standard Google search has yielded decent results, but just wondering if this already exists somewhere.

More specifically, does anyone know of attorneys in the Chicago area that work in the Bitcoin related areas.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the magnitude and urgency of your question, you might want to try contacting the Bitcoin Foundation:

[Coindesk reported](http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-foundation-forms-committees-for-legal-defence-and-regulation/) in July that the Foundation formed a Legal Defense Committee of which [Brian Klein](http://weblaw.usc.edu/contact/contactInfo.cfm?detailID=71030) is the chairman. Either his office, or the Bitcoin Foundation's General Counsel [Patrick Murck's](https://bitcoinfoundation.org/contact) office should be able to answer legal questions or refer you to someone.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that they are hard to find.

Possibly try contacting these 2 lawyers?

http://www.amazon.com/Trace-Mayer-J.D./e/B00BH3IZLA/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1
http://www.amazon.com/Bill-Rounds-Esq./e/B00BHHQ5FE/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_2